# Vagrant/GAE provision fail with puppet

Tags: google-app-engine, provisioning, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to set up vagrant with GAE. I've got the VM up and running fine, but get a fail when using puppet. Here is my command output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Running provisioner: puppet...
Running Puppet with default.pp...
stdin: is not a tty
←[0;33mwarning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/Exec[aptitude-update-1]/returns: executed succe ssfully←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/Exec[add-apt-repository]/returns: executed suc
cessfully←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/Exec[aptitude-update-2]/returns: executed succ
essfully←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/Exec[npm-grunt-cli]/returns: executed successf
ully←[0m
←[1;35merr: /Stage[main]/Grunt/Exec[npm-install]/returns: change from notrun to
0 failed: /usr/bin/npm install returned 255 instead of one of [0] at /tmp/vagran
t-puppet/modules-0/grunt/manifests/init.pp:47←[0m
←[0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Grunt/File[/usr/bin/grunt-compile]: Dependency Exec[
npm-install] has failures: true←[0m
←[0;33mwarning: /Stage[main]/Grunt/File[/usr/bin/grunt-compile]: Skipping becaus
e of failed dependencies←[0m
```

(then a load more "skipping because of failed dependencies") then:

```
←[0;36mnotice: Finished catalog run in 29.71 seconds←[0m
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
puppet apply --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' --
detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

This is my first time trying to use Vagrant; any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Exec[npm-install] failed. If you put the parameter 'logoutput => on_failure' into that exec (you should be able to find it in modules-0/grunt/manifests/init.pp:47) then you might have more of an idea as to why it failed.

Basically puppet tried to run a command on the VM and the command failed. Other stuff depended on that command working so the entire run fails.